# create a white rgba / CSS3

Tags: css

I'm customizing a plugin that uses css3's rgba throughout, I'm trying to figure out how to toggle it for it to render white with the opacity. At default it's near the shade of `#333`, and my attempts area leading it to blue or brown. Whats the white customization numbers? below is what I'm using?

```
background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
```

Comment: try 1px white transparent PNG

Comment: @enloz all programmers should use the new technologies!!! because we hate IE8 and below and we want to show the people that IE is bad. Because then they won't use it anymore.

Comment: @Louie `rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)` is not blueish or brownish. It's a shade of gray...

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The code you have is a white with low opacity.

If something white with a low opacity is above something black, you end up with a lighter shade of gray. Above red? Lighter red, etc. That is how opacity works.

Here is a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XAU9U/).

If you want it to look 'more white', make it less opaque:

`background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XAU9U/1/)

Answer (score 9):

For completely transparent color, use:

```
rbga(255,255,255,0)
```

A little more visible:

```
rbga(255,255,255,.3)
```

Comment: Typo, is rgba. I couldn't udpate it because is less than 6 chars

Answer (score 3):

I believe

```
rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.8 )
```

is equivalent in shade with `#333`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8MVC5/1/

Answer (score 1):

For white color

```
rgba(225,225,225, 0.4)
```

for black color

```
rgba
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).